# No implementation found

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have an Android app needs to reference and use some native C++ code.  I'm an experienced Java dev, but my C++ is lacking.  I'm struggling to get it to run.  I'm getting the error below.  If I change the name inside of loadLibrary, it crashes immediately, so I'm assuming that the load works fine.  How do I fix this?

```
No implementation found for boolean com.example.myapplication.BamBridge.test() (tried Java_com_example_myapplication_BamBridge_test and Java_com_example_myapplication_BamBridge_test__)


public class BamBridge implements IBamBridge {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    private native boolean test();
}
```

BAM.h:

```
#ifndef BAM_H
#define BAM_H
#define JNIIMPORT
#define JNIEXPORT  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define JNICALL
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>



extern "C" JNIEXPORT JNICALL bool test();

#endif
```

BAM.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "BAM.h"

#define SWAP_UINT16(val)  ((val << 8) | (val >> 8))






JNIEXPORT JNICALL    bool test()
{
     return true;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)



add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/BAM.cpp )
```

Comment: I think you really meant `extern "C"`...

Comment: Changing to "C" nets a compilation error:  error: declaration of 'test' has a different language linkage

Comment: You need `extern "C"` in the *header* file (and make sure that the header file is included in all relevant source files, including the one where you define the function).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That results in the same issue.  I've updated the question to reflect your comments.

Comment: Your C++ function does not have the name it was expected to have (`Java_com_example_myapplication_BamBridge_test`), and therefore wasn't found.

Comment: Ha, that's it.  Is there a way to provide hints to the java side so that we don't have to change cpp library function names?  Make this your answer and I'll accept...

Comment: @Darthg8r No, you MUST change the C side.  You can specify, on the C side, a different name mapping.  But its a giant pain in the neck, its easier to just use the correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the C side change your function name to

```
Java_com_example_myapplication_BamBridge_test
```

As java searches for the function in the specific format.

In your Header file:

```
extern "C" 
{
    JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_BamBridge_test(JNIEnv *, jobject);
}
```

In your CPP file:

```
extern "C"
{
    jboolean Java_com_example_myapplication_BamBridge_test(JNIEnv * env, jobject this)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```